# Why order of given distribution is zero?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, solution-verification

I was reading the order of distribution.

In-text they provide an example of order zero distribution

[image]

I wanted to check  my understanding . Please check my argument.

$K\subset \Omega$ be any compact set

$\phi\in D_K$

$|T_{\lambda}\phi|=|\int_K\phi d\lambda|$ $\leq ||\phi||_{\infty}\lambda(K) $

This is true for all K so N=0 here.

Thanks a lot

Comment: This is mostly correct. As the measure is signed your last inequality is not true. But yes, as the bound only involves the sup and no derivatives and a constant depending on the compact set only it is order zero.

Comment: In addition to previous comment I want to say that you need to replace your measure by its total variation (and the desired inequality then holds).